# Mounting partition times out during boot but worked

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, systemd

When I boot the system, I have to wait for 1 minute 30 seconds every time. A start job is running which is mouning a FAT32 partition to a folder in my home folder. The start job times out and I’m in emergency mode. I press enter and boot process resumes normally. When I log in, the FAT32 partition is properly mounted, which is strange because then, why wait for the timeout?

This is the fstab line:

```
UUID=6358-CC70   /home/ask/EigeneDaten  vfat    umask=0000,user,rw,utf8 0   0
```

I read a lot about these types of start job partition timeout issues. Apparently, most of the time the UUID changed and this causes the problem. This is not the case here. I triple checked the UUID. I even updated the partition’s UUID and updated it in fstab. So what else can the the cause of the timeout?

Comment: try `sudo update-initramfs -u` and `sudo update-grub` the system map may be wrong

Comment: I suspect it's your umask.

Comment: The preceding suggestions are both worth pursuing. Another possibility is filesystem damage. This is common on systems that dual-boot with Windows because of the Windows Fast Startup and Hibernate features. See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for information on disabling these features.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.
I executed 'sudo update-initramfs -u' and 'sudo update-grub'. I got no error messages. However, it didn’t fix the problem.
I get that umask is about permissions. But what could I have configured wrong? What should I change?
And if its filesystem damage, what can I do about it?